# Coming vs. Going

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Following is a classic example of the difference between the verbs ***come*** and ***go***. To complete the gap, should I use *coming* or *going*?

Immigration is the process of......to live in a foreign country.

Comment: It's called _immigration_ from the point of view of the  country the people are moving to, so logically it would have to be _coming_. _Emigration_ is _going_ to live in another country.

Answer (score 1):

One meaning of "go" is "to leave a place; depart" and therefore it fits *emigration* quite well. Another meaning of "go" is "move or proceed, especially to or from something", and so it's possible to use "go" for *immigration* also, because it refers to generic movement.

You might imagine that "come" is the opposite of "go" and so it should fit "immigration". Indeed, "immigration" and "coming to a new country" are closely aligned.

The problem is that your example sentence seems to be spoken by an omniscient narrator who doesn't reside anywhere. The same voice might say

> Spain is on the Iberian Peninsula.

Where is the speaker? Probably not in Spain.

Now, if someone said

> He is coming to Spain.

It means they are already in Spain, so it's okay. But in your example sentence, the narrator is not already in the so-called "foreign country".

[wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come#Etymology_1) has five definitions to consider:

> To move towards the speaker

**No.** Where is the speaker?

> To move towards the listener

**No.** This sentence doesn't seem to be addressed to a personal listener.

> To move towards the object that is the focus of the sentence

*Maybe.*  The difficulty is that "a foreign country" is not a clear focus of the sentence. Which country is it?

> (in subordinate clauses and gerunds) To move towards the agent or subject of the main clause.

**No.**  Who is the agent or subject here?

> To move towards an unstated agent.

**No.**  Who is the agent?

You could solve the problem by swapping "a foreign country" with a specific country and thereby allowing the listener to imagine the narrator is residing in that country.

> Immigration is the process of coming to live (permanently) in the UK.